# Looking for a virtual machine that supports 132x43 text mode or higher

Tags: software-rec, virtual-machine, virtualization

I'm looking for any virtual machine that supports VESA text mode 132x43 or higher. Bonus points if it works on Windows, boots from floppy image and is free software.

This may seem like a silly question, but it appears that not many VMs do support the 132 modes. So far I've tried Bochs, VirtualBox, VMWare Workstation and DosBox and it appears that none of them support that mode which I need for a certain application I'm supposed to write. Unfortunately all real computers I have use nVidia video cards and they removed support for that mode sometime during the GeForce FX era so I don't have a computer which can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Virtualbox with Remote console which uses RDP?

Not sure whether that supports this mode, but it may be worth a try. I have used RDP to access the text console on Virtualbox VMs that were running headless.